# Why does 'A a{};' compile when the default constructor A::A() is deleted?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, uniform-initialization

Here's the code example in question:

```
struct A {
    A() = delete;
};

int main()
{
//  A a(); // compiles, since it's a function declaration (most vexing parse)
//  A a;   // does not compile, just as expected
    A a{}; // compiles, why? The default constructor is deleted.
}
```

Try it [here](https://godbolt.org/g/RB9iLo) with any of the available compilers. I tried with several and didn't find one that gave a compilation error.

Comment: There was such question already, check this: [Deleted default constructor. Objects can still be created… sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33988297/deleted-default-constructor-objects-can-still-be-created-sometimes).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that it's a duplicate. I wouldn't want to delete it though since it's a more concise version — I forwarded this question here because neither I nor the person who asked me could find the linked original.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a current language issue that is very likely to be fixed soon. The proposal that tackles the necessary design change can be found [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1008r0.pdf). From the abstract of the proposal:

> C++ currently allows some types with user-declared constructors to be initialized via aggregate
>   initialization, bypassing those constructors. The result is code that is surprising, confusing,
>   and buggy

Comment: "Language defect" means something specific. This is not a language defect. This is a design change.

Comment: @Barry Thanks for the hint, I'll fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Because `A` is an [aggregate type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), then given `A a{};` aggregate initialization is performed.

> Each `direct public base, (since C++17)` array element, or non-static class member, in order of array subscript/appearance in the class definition, is copy-initialized from the corresponding clause of the initializer list.

In aggregate initialization, every member or element (if any) will be copy-initialized directly, the constructor is bypassed; so it's `delete`ed or not doesn't matter.

Note that explicitly deleted constructors are allowed for aggregate types (since C++11) (until C++20),

> no user-provided constructors (explicitly defaulted or deleted constructors are allowed) (since C++11) (until C++17)
>
> no user-provided, inherited, or explicit constructors (explicitly defaulted or deleted constructors are allowed) (since C++17) (until C++20)